# ffmpeg-php silent setting

Tags: php, ffmpeg

does ffmpeg-php have a silent setting or any way to keep it from displaying errors? the closest I've seen were for running ffmpeg via command line in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, but as a sort if work around you could install your own error handler which could catch and sort your ffmpeg errors. It's cleaner than using the @ symbol and has worked for me in the past.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php